# Custom React hook, infinite loop only if I add the second dependency. Bug or something I can't understand?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've made a really simple React hook. That's something seen on many guides and websites:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export const useFetchRemote = (remote, options, initialDataState) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(initialDataState);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get(remote, options);
      setData(result.data);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [remote]);

  return data;
};
```

Example usage:

```js
import { useFetchRemote } from '../utils';

export const UserList = () => {
  const users = useFetchRemote('/api/users', {}, []);

  return (
    <ul>
      {users.map(user => <li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

**This is working**. If I understand correctly:

- With no dependencies like `useEffect(() => { /*...*/ })`, setting the state into the function would trigger a re-render, calling `useEffect` again, in an infinite loop.
- With empty dependencies like `useEffect(() => { /*...*/ }, [])`, my function will be called only the "very first time" component is mounted.

So, in my case, `remote` is a dependency. My function should be called again if remote changes. This is true also for `options`. If I add also `options`, the infinite loop starts. I can't understand... why this is happening?

```js
export const useFetchRemote = (remote, options, initialDataState) => {
  // ...

  useEffect(() => {
      // ...
  }, [remote, options]);

  // ...
};
```

Comment: Is the `options` parameter an `object` or an `array`? If yes, then probably its reference changes in every render where do you call this custom hook. So, maybe you can memoize it if possible or you can use something like [use-deep-compare-effect](https://github.com/kentcdodds/use-deep-compare-effect) or as a dirty(?) solution `JSON.stringify(options)`.

Comment: @devserkan is an object, but I'm passing an empty object... for testing purposes. So I doubt it will change. I've edited the question to include an example of usage.

Comment: Empty or not I guess it does not matter. If the component where you use this hook gets rendered, then the empty object's reference will change.

Comment: show me the main component you are calling your custom hook in, your custom hook is valid.

Comment: @AhmedMagdy question updated. Also, could be simplified further removing `loading` and `error` state. I'll simplify it further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The infinite loop is caused by the fact that your `options` parameter is an object literal, which creates a new reference on every render of `UserList`. Either create a constant reference by defining a constant outside the scope of `UserList` like this:

```
const options = {};
const initialDataState = [];

export const UserList = () => {
  // or for variable options instead...
  // const [options, setOptions] = useState({});
  const users = useFetchRemote('/api/users', options, initialDataState);

  return (
    <ul>
      {users.map(user => <li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

or if you intend the `options` parameter to be effectively constant for each usage of the `userFetchRemote()` hook, you can do the equivalent of initializing props into state and prevent the reference from updating on every render:

```
export const useFetchRemote = (remote, options, initialDataState) => {
  const [optionsState] = useState(options);
  const [data, setData] = useState(initialDataState);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get(remote, optionsState);
      setData(result.data);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [remote, optionsState]);
  // ---------^

  return data;
};
```

This second approach will prevent a new fetch from occuring though, if the options are dynamically changed on a particular call site of `useFetchRemote()`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm reading and studying your answer. I've made some changes to my first example to make it simple.

Comment: This is what I meant and with good solution options. I didn't think that you're the one creating the `options`.

Comment: @gremo I updated my answer to reflect the changes in your question

Comment: Just to elaborate on this, React uses `Object.is()` to determine whether the effect callback should be called. `Object.is('/api/users', '/api/users') // true` but `Object.is({}, {}) // false`.

Comment: As I'm still learning React, your answer scares me. I need to understard it. So, to be clear: React see the `UserList` component, and the first render occurs. My custom hook is invoked with a "first reference" to the object literal parameter (named `options`). What's happening next? I'm altering the state inside the hook (`setDat`a), so React will trigger another render; my `useEffect` will be invoked again, because the `options` object has been "changed" in the second render?

Comment: @gremo `const foo = () => ({}); foo() !== foo();`. You understand this, right? It's the same thing, each invocation of `useFetchRemote()` will be passed a new reference, even though it's the same object literal. And yes the second render is causing by `setLoading(true)`, trigerring `useEffect()` to be invoked after every render because each render has a new reference for `options`.

Comment: And if your options are static you can skip creating local state for them and instead hoist them outside the component where you call `useFetchRemote`. They will still be within scope to use them as function arguments.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts perfectly clear. So how to deal with the options being a state inside the `UserList` component (that is not fixed, changed based on something in the UI)? `const options = useState({});` would lead to the same problem if I understand correctly. Solution two, I suppose.

Comment: @gremo no, that would not lead to the same problem. New fetches would only occur after calls to `setOptions()`, not on every render.